# en Blazor, ¿ como configurar algunos aspectos visuales de las páginas usando variables cargadas desde un archivo de texto?

Tags: blazor

Blazor server.

En wwwroot/Info tengo un archivo Config.txt cuyo contenido es:

ColorFondo: <elcolorelegido, por ejemplo azure>

FontSize: <eltamañodelaletra por ejemplo 20px>

MainLayout.razor

---

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


@{
    Config.Iniciar();
}

<div class="page">
    
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>

        <main>

            <article class="content px-4">
                <style>
                    body {
                        background-color: @Config.ColorFondo;
                    }

                    p {
                        font-size: @Config.FontSize;
                    }
                </style>

                @Config.ColorFondo;
                @Body

            </article>
        </main>

</div>
```

---

Config es una abstract class, con variables globales:

---

```
public abstract class Config
{
    private static bool iniciado = false;

    public static string RootPath { get; set; } = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");

    public static string ColorFondo { get; set; } = "azure";
    public static string FontSize { get; set; } = "20px";

    public static void Iniciar()
    {
        if (iniciado) return;
        iniciado = true;

        string nfichero = "Config.txt";
        string[]? fichero = null;


        var dataFile = Path.Combine(RootPath, "Info", nfichero);


        if (File.Exists(dataFile))
        {
            fichero = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
            if (fichero != null)
            {
                foreach (string s in fichero)
                {
                    var sp = s.Split(":");
                    if (sp.Length == 2)
                    {
                        if (sp[0].Trim().ToLower() == "colorfondo") ColorFondo = sp[1].Trim();
                        if (sp[0].Trim().ToLower() == "fontsize")
                        {
                            int ftsz = 0;
                            try
                            {
                                ftsz = int.Parse(sp[1].Trim());
                            }
                            catch { }
                            if (ftsz > 0)
                            {
                                FontSize = ftsz + "px";
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

---

**Todo esto funciona**: según cambio los valores en config.txt, la página muestra el color de fondo y tamaño de letra correspondientes.

**PROBLEMA!!**: cuando cambio los valores, los cambios no se reflejan hasta que reinicio el servidor web (IIS). Es como si hubiera una cache que impide ver los cambios realizados. Es decir, no vuelve a leer el archivo Config.txt hasta que se reinicia el servidor.

Comment: Es Blazor Wasm o Server??? Además agrega el código que lee el archivo

Comment: gracias yussef. se trata de blazor server y he añadido el código que faltaba

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente encontré el problema:

lo que pasa:

Blazor trata una clase abstracta como Global par la sesión de aplicación, compartiéndola para todas las sesiones de cliente. Así, una vez que inciado es true, lo tiene para todas las sesiones de cliente, incluso nuevas.

Averigué esto sustituyendo iniciado por contador, como sigue:

```
public static int Contador = 0;

if (Contador >0) then return;
Contador++;
```

y escribiendo @Config.Contador antes de @Body en MainLayout

el contador se incrementa conforme el usuario inicia una nueva sesión (incluso en una máquina diferente) o navega por las distintas páginas de la aplicación.

el contador nunca vuelve a 0 a menos que se reinicie la aplicación (por ejemplo reiniciando IIS)